# Qual o tipo que devo utilizar para salvar apenas a hora (sem data) em um banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tipagem, time

Estou em dúvida em qual tipo devo usar para trabalhar com horas em meu sistema. Devo usar `DateTime`, `Time` ou `TimeStamp`. Gostaria que as horas ficassem salvas nesse formato:

```
HH:MM
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existe um tipo específico para isto que é o [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html). Este tipo possui os segundos e fração deles também (mantenha-os zerados se não precisa deles), mas em geral não será problema.

Mas nem sempre é necessário usá-lo. Há algumas situações que um tipo `VARCHAR` pode ser suficiente. Claro que ele é mais limitado, não tem a melhor semântica, mas depende da utilização. Se deseja realmente evitar os segundos, seria esta forma. Você terá que tratar os dados manualmente.

Por outro lado é possível que este tipo não seja suficiente para o que deseja e precise usar outro tipo onde tenha mais controle, mesmo que seja a custo de menos facilidades. Em alguns casos poderá ser o `VARCHAR` mesmo. Em outros pode ser interessante o uso do `DATETIME` ou `TIMESTAMP`, mesmo que eles tenham informações irrelevantes.

Só vendo a situação exata para decidir qual é o melhor. Mas eu irei nos tipos nativos em primeiro lugar. Se for o caso pecar pelo excesso seria mais vantajoso na maioria dos casos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendo, no meu caso eu estou fazendo uma agenda. Onde tenho hora inicial e hora final de um compromisso. E futuramente deverá existir uma comparação para que eu não possa adicionar nenhum compromisso se já exista algum no horário cadastrado. Nesse caso seria melhor usar qual forma?

Comment: Eu ficaria com o `TIME` mesmo. Mantendo os segundos sempre zerados.

Comment: Entendi, dai no meu código java eu passo o valor `hh:mm` para variáveis do tipo `DATE` do pacote `java.sql.date` ?

Comment: É, então, aí tem que ver melhor. Nesse contexto pode ser interessante usar o `DATETIME` para compatibilizar com o Java. Mesmo que tenha informação supérflua. Você pode usar o [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html). A decisão não é simples. Dê uma lida nisto: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Comment: Vou tentar fazer aqui ja volto pra dizer se deu certo

Comment: Consegui fazer aqui, a hora ficou salva nesse formato: `13:00:00.000` mas acho que não tem problema. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu usaria o Time também, se futuramente você quiser ordenar não funcionaria com o varchar